# I would like this question to be reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

I asked a question on using placeholders in MySQL 'cooperative' locking. The question is found here [Using placeholders in MySQL 'COOPERATIVE' LOCK queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60524728/using-placeholders-in-mysql-cooperative-lock-queries)

Then it got closed. I was directed to a possible duplicate here [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement). I honestly do not think there is sufficient reason to believe that these two questions are essentially the same.

1. Even though the earlier question has a little similarity to my own, the similarity is not so much as to label it a duplicate. There is a world of difference, as it seems to me. I already looked for a similar question before I asked mine but did not get.
2. A user gave an answer before the question was closed. I thought the answer was okay and upvoted it. Another user said the answer was "essentially wrong" and therefore was undeserving of an upvote. When I asked for clarification, none was provided. Rather, the question was closed by the same user who insinuated that the answer was "essentially wrong".
3. In MySQL advisory lock, even though "SELECT" is used, there is no mention of a particular table, just a string. So, it seems unclear to me how that question should be termed a duplicate of another that is explicitly INSERTing rows into a table.
4. What I really wanted to know in my question was whether advisory lock could use prepared statement in a situation when another the named string is made up of literal string and another input appended to it.
5. I did not find a single question that mentioned what I wanted to do. I think the question should be allowed to stay for others to learn.
6. Much as I have struggled to not mention this, I believe the user who closed my question did so, not really because it was a duplicate but because the fellow has the power to single-handedly close the question; And he did so after the exchange of comments, not before. The timeline is there for everyone to see.

Edit:
In the question [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), We have

```
$query = "INSERT INTO contents (type, reporter, description) 
         VALUES(?, ?, 'whatever')";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$type, $reporter]);
```

I already understand that.

In my question, we have

```
//code
"SELECT GET_LOCK( 'unique_string', -1 ) AS acquired"
// code
return ( $row['acquired'] == 1);
```

Now knowing that the first param in `GET_LOCK()` is a string, I originally thought `"SELECT GET_LOCK( 'unique_string'. $year, -1 ) AS acquired"` was the way to go, keeping in place the string. So, I wanted to know how the placeholder would fit in.

In fact, while I contemplated another option, namely to do something like `$string = unique_string . $year`, then do `"SELECT GET_LOCK( :string, -1 ) AS acquired"`, the user who answered the question pointed me in the right direction with unnamed placeholder by using `"SELECT GET_LOCK( '?', -1 ) AS acquired"` followed by `$stmt->execute( array( $string ) );`

The thing to keep in mind is that `GET_LOCK()` requires parameter 1 to be a string with quotes. I thought that would always be the case.

Comment: As *Your Common Sense* solely closed the question, you can ping them in the question's comments and ask them to revert the closure; just make sure you include reasoning in the comment or question (preferably the latter) on why it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Larnu, I have done so. I hope he will do just that. Thank you very much.

Comment: ".. not really because it was a duplicate *but because the fellow has the power to single-handedly close* the question ..." Your Common Sense has earned a gold badge in `mysql` by answering several *thousands* of questions. One would earlier assume the dup-vote is because of this knowledge rather than your strong suggestion of "because he can".

Comment: May I suggest editing your points about why your question is not a duplicate to the question itself? Points 3 and 4 are what matters. Point 1 is.... not really relevant, unless you point to what you found and how it didn't help. Point 2 is absolutely irrelevant. Questions are questions, answers are answers. The fact a question can have an answer doesn't mean it's not a dupe. Point 5 is pretty much point 1. And Point 6 is targeted to the behavior of a user, not to your question and its difference.

Comment: If users who could (including myself) closed questions *"because the fellow has the power to single-handedly close the question"* then SO, or even the SE community as a whole would revoke that privilege from us. Gold Badgers can close questions as dupes because they are *trusted* to know the subject matter. Likewise, however, they can solely revoke those closures.

Comment: @Patrice, I clearly understand that I am in a very bad situation. Notice that I prefaced point 6 with "Much as I have struggled to not mention this". I knew that would be the case that people would say I targeted persons.  But no, I did not. But thank you for you suggestions.

Comment: @yivi, Yes, you are right.I focused on it because that was my problem. Well, I don't think what my problem boils down to should be used to judge. Anyway, I understand your point. Thanks.

Comment: Care to explain why the answers in the dupe do not answer your question? Why can't you use those techniques in your case?

Comment: @yivi, Where should I put that explanation? Do I edit my post here or add it as a comment?

Comment: You're basically already in conversation with YCS in the comments to your question. Clarify there. I also fail to see how your question differs in any way from simply using parameterised queries. That you're using those in a locking context is pretty darn irrelevant.

Comment: @Stephen point 6 is basically "he did it, not because he was right, but because he can". How can this **not** be targeted to someone? :/. It's entirely irrelevant. It could be a mistake. Could be he has a cat that walked across his desk and hit the right (wrong?) key. Could be a genuine case of morning brain. It's irrelevant. Is your question a dupe or not? That's all that should matter.

Comment: @Patrice The generally accepted phrasing there is [*"Tim lost his keys again"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/476). 

Comment: @Patrice, Yes, I thought so. But I maintain I did not target his person in my post here. I thought he did it because of the circumstances.

Answer (score 11):

Your question **is** a duplicate of [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) (among many other similar questions on the site).

Even if you are focusing in a particular use case, the general solution still applies: bound parameters to avoid SQL injections.

You want to execute something like:

```sql
SELECT IS_USED_LOCK( 'unique_string' ) AS connection_id
```

where `unique_string` is partly supplied by the user.

Given that, what you need to do is simply concatenate the user provided string and your unique string prior bounding the parameter, and then simply use the answers in the duplicate (which are similar to the one you got and upvoted, minus the errors in that one).:

```php
$lock  = 'unique_string' . $user_provided_string;
$query = 'SELECT IS_USED_LOCK( ? ) AS connection_id';
$stmt  = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$lock]);
```

I think you didn't immediately realize your question was a duplicate because you got distracted by the "cooperative locking" aspect of your issue. But deeper inspection would tell you that it is actually irrelevant, and actually trying the answers in the linked dupe would have confirmed it.

There is nothing wrong in asking a duplicate question. The user who closed it as a dupe is just trying to help you and future users in getting to the right place to get answers.

---

> What I really wanted to know in my question was whether advisory lock could use prepared statement in a situation when another the named string is made up of literal string and another input appended to it.

If your question is "can I use prepared statements for these queries", then the comments you would get would be of the kind of *"Well, have you tried it for yourself?"*. This is basic research for any kind of question. If you want to know if X works, for something that easily testable, you are expected to have tried it yourself. If it **doesn't**, now you have the beginning of question.

> I did not find a single question that mentioned what I wanted to do. I think the question should be allowed to stay for others to learn

That's only because you focused too much in your use case, and didn't realize that the general solution applied. That's fine, it happens. Although again, doing additional research on your end (trying out the solution, in this case), it's always a great idea.

> A user gave an answer before the question was closed. I thought the answer was okay and upvoted it.

Yes, and the answer was entirely too similar to answers in the dupe. That would have been a big hint that the question was indeed a dupe. The answer contained a couple of minor but fatal syntax errors though.

Comment: Just to know. What is the difference between duplicate and similar? You said (among many other similar questions on the site)

Comment: Duplicate means, in SO parlance: "it can be answered by the answers over _there_". Similar is just similar.

Comment: "Similar is just similar" and. "Yes, and the answer was entirely too similar to answers in the dupe"

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean by that last comment.

Comment: @Stephen Duplicate is for **questions**. Not answers. A dupe means "the answer on this duplicate question is similar enough to the answer you need you can take it to answer your own question". Yivi didn't say the answer was a duplicate, cause in SO parlance, duplication isn't for answers but questions. A bit confusing verbiage at times, but overall the point doesn't change. Unless we go down semantics just for semantics sake

Comment: related: [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217401/165773)

Comment: @Patrice, you seem to be getting it a bit.When yivi said "(among many other similar questions on the site)", I wanted him to define what similar means. He did not. When he said "similar is just similar", and you said " A bit confusing webpage at times", I understand that I was  not entirely wrong in my original question. I got it. We are on SO.

Comment: @Stephen what Yivi meant by "similar is similar" is (I assume) that they say "some questions are alike without being duplicated". Considering "duplicated" means "the answers on the dupe-target answer your question". Similar would mean "it looks close to your question, but you can't apply the answers to your question". In your case, I believe this was a legitimate duplicate, not just similarities

Comment: Stephen, "duplicate" has a specific meaning on SO. "Similar", does not. You would need to go to the dictionary. E.g.: _"having a resemblance in appearance, character, or quantity, without being identical"_. I don't understand what do you mean by "I was not entirely wrong in my original question". It seems like you were wrong, but don't want to learn from the experience.

Comment: I feel there's a breakdown in communication here between the three of you. It's pointless to continue discussing the difference between "similar" and "duplicate". Just [let it go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0MK7qz13bU).